# What is a "back to back" firewall configuration?

Tags: firewall, networking, topology

I've found [some guides](https://itsalwaysthenetwork.wordpress.com/2017/09/09/back-to-back-firewalls-and-l3-loops/) talking about "*back to back*" (or *back2back*) configuration but I can't find an explanation of such configuration.

Can somebody explain what is meant by "back-to-back"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a kind of topology when you put your internal network behind a firewall, then you create another network for services purposes called dmz and finally you´ve added another firewall to the external network.

it's like this:

LAN--->>>---INTERNAL FIREWALL--->>>---DMZ--->>>---EXTERNAL FIREWALL

Advantages
Isolates customer-facing and partner-facing content to a separate perimeter network.
Content publishing can be automated.
If content in the perimeter network is compromised or corrupted as a result of Internet access, the integrity of the content in the corporate network is retained.

Disadvantages
Requires more hardware to maintain two separate farms.
Data overhead is greater. Content is maintained and coordinated in two different farms and networks.
Changes to content in the perimeter network are not reflected in the corporate network. Consequently, content publishing to the perimeter domain is not a workable choice for extranet sites that are collaborative.